# URL template optional param

Tags: django, django-urls

Let's consider this template part

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{% if client_id %}
    {% url client_edit client_id=client_id %}{% else %}
    {% url client_edit %}
    {% endif %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ client_form }}
</form>
```

As you can see the parameter `client_id` is optional.

Is there a way to avoid this repetition (`url client_edit`) ?

---

Url pattern:

```
url('^client/edit$', client_edit, name='client_edit'),
url('^client/edit/(?P<client_id>\d+)$', client_edit, name='client_edit'),
```

Comment: Maybe `{% url client_edit client_id=client_id|default_if_none:"" %}` (certainly not tested!)

Comment: Does this form tie back to a model?

Comment: This id is related to 2 modelForms. Question updated. @TimmyO'Mahony my url pattern doesn't allow an empty `client_id`, should it change it somehow ?

Comment: Is there any relation between user model and this client_id?

Comment: Yes, does it make a difference ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not repetition of using

```
{% url client_edit %}
```

since you actualy define two urls. If you really want to make it shorter (not necessary simplier) you could create some filter like

```
{{client_id|make_url}}
```

and inside filter you can resolve to proper url

Comment: That could be an idea, in that case I would try to create one that takes the url name in parameter because I need it for all my CRUDs. I find weird that there is no simple way to do it.

Comment: Or maybe I should use only one URL with optional param in it

Answer (score 1):

urls don't have optional parameters. You can have multiple patterns point to the same view (as you have done), and then check for the defaults in the view. In your template, `{%  url client_edit client_id=client_id|default_if_none:-1 %}`, then depending on what you want to happen on the view end filter appropriately:

```
def client_edit(request, client_id = None):
    if client_id:
        client = get_object_or_404(Client, pk=client_id)
    else:
        # Default value for client
        client = Client.objects.filter(active=True) # for example 
    # your normal logic here
```